# access a static field of a result type of function that has the same name with type

Tags: c#, class, static

ok this may sound a little crazy but, i have class A and a function, returns an instance of A, also called A() and i have to access a static field of class A.

```
 public class A
  {
    public static int Num = 1;

  }

class Program
  {

    public A A()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(A.Num); // Error points here. A.Num.
      return new A();
    }
  }
```

and i get

> 'Program.A()' is a 'method', which is
>   not valid in the given context

what is the solution?
thanks.

Comment: change the method name A() to B()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the namesapce instead

```
namesapce test {
      public class A
        {
            public static int Num = 1;

        }

        class Programs:A
        {

            public A A()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(test.A.Num);
                return new A();
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can specify the namespace:

```
Console.WriteLine(Foo.Bar.A.Num);
```

If there's no namespace, use the global namespace alias:

```
Console.WriteLine(global::A.Num);
```